# Avoiding a null return set

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I make a query always return something, a default value when it does not find what I am looking for?

For example, in the following query:

```
SELECT 
            food_id,
            drink_id,
            payment_amount, 
            count(*) AS total_payments,
            payment_amount * count(*) AS total_benefit
            FROM foods pc
            INNER JOIN drinks px
            ON pc.id = px.food_id
            AND pc.drink_id = 25
            GROUP BY food_id, drink_id;
```

when pc.id is not equal to px.food_id I get an empty set. I am looking for something such as:

```
SELECT 
            food_id DEFAULT IF NOTHING 5,
            drink_id DEFAULT IF NOTHING 25,
            payment_amount DEFAULT IF NOTHING 0, 
            count(*) AS total_payments DEFAULT IF NOTHING 0,
            payment_amount * count(*) AS total_benefit DEFAULT 0
            FROM foods pc
            INNER JOIN drinks px
            ON pc.id = px.food_id
            AND pc.drink_id = 25
            GROUP BY food_id, drink_id;
```

Any ways of doing something like the above?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an empty result set because of the inner join.  This should probably be an outer join.  Combining this with Rup's answer is probably what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
        COALESCE(food_id, 0) AS food_id,
        COALESCE(drink_id, 25) AS drink_id,
        COALESCE(payment_amount, 0) as payment_amount,
        count(*) AS total_payment,
        COALESCE(payment_amount, 0) * count(*) AS total_benefit
        FROM foods pc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN drinks px
        ON pc.id = px.food_id
        AND pc.drink_id = 25
        GROUP BY food_id, drink_id;
```

Comment: This will always return every food, even if they're not associated to the drink specified.  I'm not certain about what the OP desires though, so +1 until the OP clarifies :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT 
            COALESCE(food_id, 0) AS food_id,
            COALESCE(drink_id, 25) AS drink_id,
            COALESCE(payment_amount, 0) as payment_amount,
            count(*) AS total_payment,
            COALESCE(payment_amount, 0) * count(*) AS total_benefit
            ...
GROUP BY COALESCE(food_id, 0), COALESCE(drink_id, 25),
         COALESCE(payment_amount, 0);
```

etc.

Comment: This will only work if there is a result set which contains NULLs in the output fields.  It won't work to compensate for an empty result set.

Comment: @Dems D'oh, yes, missed that. +1 to Tevo.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT food_id, drink_id, payment_amount, COUNT(*) AS total_payments,
      payment_amount * COUNT(*) AS total_benefit
   FROM foods pc 
      INNER JOIN drinks px
         ON pc.id = px.food_id
            AND pc.drink_id = 25
   GROUP BY food_id, drink_id 
UNION
SELECT 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   FROM MySystemTableAlwaysHasExactlyOneRow 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT * 
                      FROM foods pc 
                         INNER JOIN drinks px
                            ON pc.id = px.food_id
                               AND pc.drink_id = 25
                     ) ;
```